# Reorder data.table rows so that no two consecutive rows are the same

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

Given data with 2N rows with at least N unique rows, is there an elegant way to reorder so that each row is different from the one above it?

Here's a simple example

```
df <- data.table(
        a = rep(2, 4),
        b = c(2, 2, 1, 1)
    )

> df
   a b
1: 2 2
2: 2 2
3: 2 1
4: 2 1
```

Rows 2 breaks the rule as it is the same as row 1 which is just above it.  Similarly row 4 breaks the rule.

Let's say `reorder_function` is the function that reorders the data, then

```
> reorder_function(df)
   a b
1: 2 2
2: 2 1
3: 2 2
4: 2 1
```

The output possibilities are not unique and it doesn't matter for my use case as long as the output satisfies the rule.

Comment: I think `df[,.(a,b,V2=1:.N), by=.(V1=rleid(a,b))][order(V2,V1), .(a,b)]` does the work. Must test a tougher example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rowid` to "Generate unique row ids within each group", here defined by columns 'a' and 'b'. `order` data by the row id.

```
df[order(rowid(a, b))]
   a b
1: 2 2
2: 2 1
3: 2 2
4: 2 1
```